# Change values in matrix if it matches a table

Tags: matlab

Hello I'm trying to do the following:

This is my table :

```
1   2   3   4   5
6   7   8   9   10
11  12  13  14  15
16  17  18  19  20
21  22  23  24  25
```

and I have a matrix [25,1].

I want to do the following: if the values in first and last columns match the numbers in the matrix, change the value to "99".

So the output should be this:

```
99
2
3
4
99
99
7
8
9
99
99
12
13
14
99
99
17
18
19
99
99
22
23
24
99
```

This is my attempt:

```
NT = zeros (x*y:1);
NT(:,1) = 1:x*y;

for i = 1:x*y
    for j = 1  
    if NT(i,j) == x1(i,j) 
       NT(i,j) = 99;

    end
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done very easily with [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html). Let

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5; 6 7 8 9 10; 11 12 13 14 15; 16 17 18 19 20; 21 22 23 24 25];
B = (1:25).';
new_value = 99;
```

Then

```
B(ismember(B, A(:, [1 end]))) = new_value;
```

gives

```
B =
    99
     2
     3
     4
    99
    99
     7
     8
     9
    99
    99
    12
    13
    14
    99
    99
    17
    18
    19
    99
    99
    22
    23
    24
    99
```